# Installation of ndnSIM 2.0 (Name Data Networking)

Tags: c++, ndnsim

I am trying to install ndnSIM 2.0 **[Link](http://ndnsim.net/2.0/)** on Ubuntu 12.04. I have followed all the instructions mentioned **[Link 2](http://ndnsim.net/2.0/getting-started.html)**.

When I run `./waf configure` while in `ndn-cxx` folder I get the following error

> Checking if CryptoPP library works: yes
>   Checking boost includes: 1.57.0
>   Checking boost libs: lib system not found in /usr/lib
>   The configuration failed
>   (complete log in /home/rani/Desktop/ndnSIM/ndn-cxx/build/config.log)

**Do I need to install some more libraries or there is some link problem as
Boost Library(1.57) is installed in /usr/local/lib? I have even followed the FAQ!**

Answer (score 0):

So ./waf cannot find the boost libs. Please check where the boost libs have been installed, most probably they are in /usr/local/lib in which case simply issue:

./waf configure --boost-libs=/usr/local/lib (instead of just ./waf configure).

You can ask any questions at their [mailing list](http://www.lists.cs.ucla.edu/mailman/listinfo/ndnsim).

Comment: you can also do ./waf configure --help for a complete list of options

Comment: Thanks ashlesh , I asked at the mailing list , and it was the same problem .The location of the boost libs should be defined accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, the error you got refers to ndn-cxx, which is our library, not ndnSIM itself.

This error indicates that your installed boost libraries could not be found by ndn-cxx.

Please make sure that you installed the boost libraries correctly and then search for the directory, where they were installed.

Typically, the boost libraries are installed under the /usr/lib directory. If your boost libraries have been installed somewhere else, you may use the following option to indicate the specific directory and configure ndn-cxx:

./waf configure --boost-libs=